# No sound when playing DVD with AxWindowsMediaPlayer in VB

Tags: wmp, wmplib, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am using the AxWMPLib AxWindowsMediaPlayer for DVD playback in VB.Net. I can play back the DVD with the installed Windows Media Player 12, but it doesn't have any sound when I play it back in my application. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer to my own question. WMP 12 uses a Dolby Digital audio codec that is only licensed for use with Microsoft's applications. An install of ffdshow did the trick.